# Which candidate symbols should I choose (or how to make GetSymbolInfo more successful)?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to obtain a symbol from many methods. 
One example is ODataUriParser.ParseFilter Method (google and you will see MS doc about it) that has 3 overloads.

My input was: `InvocationExpression ODataUriParser.ParseFilter(filterString, EdmModel, TableServiceEntity)`

Unfortunately the symbol was not successfully found and the 3 overloads was provided as candidate symbols.
Researching I found something that exactly explains what I got, see below.
However, I want to still use these the candidate symbols. What would the best way to do choose, or, maybe, is there a way to make the symbol finding more successful?

From @joshvarty's [website](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/).

*> [SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo()](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Extensions.cs,6d0ce5ad095fe519) accepts expression syntax  (eg. InvocationExpressionSyntax) and returns a symbol. If the model could not successfully resolve a symbol, it provides candidate symbols which can serve as best guesses.*

Comment: If you're analyzing code you expect to build, then you might want to call Compilation.GetDiagnostics() to verify that there aren't compiler errors. If you have broken references or something else got set wrong, it's possible some cascading errors is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can look at the `CandidateReason` and make a decision about which one is most applicable in your scenario.

In practice, in VS, we usually just use the [first one](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/R/8954d138478c33cc.html) :)

Comment: In this example the reason is _OverloadResolutionFailure_. (But I understand I might face the others too). 
I see that even though there are multiple candidate symbols, there is only a single reason. So I guess I can't use the reason to choose in between them. 
But the reason will be helpful to decide if use the candidates at all or not.